# Do 30% of seniors get a heart attack each year?

Tags: mortality, cardiology

I saw an ad somewhere that claimed 30% of seniors die each year from heart attack. This sounds way, *way* too much. Is it really true?

Comment: Not quite, but [1 in 4 deaths](http://www.cdc.gov/heartdisease/facts.htm) every year (in the USA) are due to heart disease.

Comment: Sounds like you misunderstood the advert. Can you link to the original ad?

Comment: @Oddthinking it was an ad on youtube, and it explicitly said "30% of seniors die of a heart attack each year. Prepare yourself yada yada yada." EDIT: Not the yada yada part :)

Comment: Is the question "get a heart attack" or "die of a heart attack"?

Comment: Was it referring to the USA? What was there product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't even pass the smell test.

[image: Death rate vs age]

See any spot on that graph where 30% of people die in a year?  Even at 85 which is the top of the graph you see less than half that rate.

Answer (score 6):

#### Not quite

In 2000-2001, 2010-2011, and 2012-2013, roughly 30% of deaths over 65 in the USA were due to heart disease (30.9, 30.5, and 29.8).

Source:  [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/hus/hus14.pdf#021)

Perhaps the advertisement simply misstated the claim.  Not 30% of those alive, just 30% of the deaths.  Also, this is all heart disease, not just heart attacks.

As the other answer notes, overall death rates are far below 30%, so this claim certainly isn't accurately describing that.

Comment: I was simply showing the original claim was impossible.  I think you nailed it as to what really is going on.